# Array size in segment tree Data structure

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, tree, segment-tree

In segment tree, we build segment tree above an array.

For Example, If array size is 8 [0-7] indexing.
Number of nodes in segment tree is 15 i.e., 1,2,4,8 in 1st,2nd,3rd,4th levls
[image]
But in a problem, if I declare structure array size as `seg tree[2*N + 1]` its giving wrong answer whereas if I declare it as below

```
struct seg{ 
 int sum;
};
seg tree[4*N + 1];
```

Its giving wrong answer. My doubt is that [2*N] is sufficient, Then why is it giving wrong answer.
[image]
Node segment(1-1) having number 9 its parent have number 4. So left child is 2*N right child is 2*N+1

Comment: Let me get my crystal ball out

Comment: @Sparrow no semicolon after `int sum`.

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar Its fixed. It might have given Compile Error? But Its giving WA if i change it to 2*N

Answer (score 0):

Let `n` be the size of the initial array. The size of the segment tree will be:

- `2*n-1` if `n` is a power of 2.
- `2*2^(log_2(n)+1)-1` if `n` is not a power of 2.

Edit: It's true that we can create just an array of size `2*n-1` to make a tree theoretically, but think about the how we can go from parent to children in the array representation of segment tree? The left child will be at index `2*i+1` (0-based indexing) and the right child will be at index `2*i+2`. To maintain this invariant, we have to construct the complete binary tree and for that the formula is mentioned above.

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28502243/3160529).

Comment: In either ways the size should be less than __2*N__. For any given **n** the maximum value node number is **2*N-1**.

Comment: _Induction_ : 1-1, 2-3, 3-5, 4-9, 5-9, 6-11, 7-13,...,N - 2N-1

Comment: For `n=5`, the size of the segment tree will be 15 not 10.

Comment: How come 15. For n = 5, if the number of the segment [0-4] is 1, then max node value occurs at [1-1] (number 9, i.e., 2*N - 1)

Comment: Did you look at the formula above? If `n=5`, `log_2(5) = 2`, `2*(2^(2+1))-1 = 15`.

Comment: It might be wrong. As you can see its 9 which is the max node value; I have updated the **figure**. See it

Comment: Try to draw a segment tree for range 1 to 10, and you will see that an array of size 19  is not sufficient to hold all the nodes.